# Timing of Passing Variable between Two UIViewControllers

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sqlite, uiviewcontroller, viewdidload

Not sure how to ask this question so it will makes sense, but let me try. My app opens a  UIViewController, and then calls another one. When it opens the other one it places a variable in a textfield successfully. When the user closes the 2nd UIViewController and returns to the 1st UIViewController, I pass back the variable and place it in a textfield. This is all successful at this point. The variable is being passed back and forth with no problems.

So here is what I am trying to do: upon returning to the 1st UIViewController I run a query statement which uses the variable in the textfield as a key to pull a record from a SQLite table. I use the NSLog to check the code and I see that the textfield is empty, but when the UIViewController appears the variable is in the textfield.

Are with me so far? I hope so…

I am running the query in the ViewDidLoad. I am thinking that the ViewDidLoad is running before it copies the variable from the 2nd into the textfield.

My main question is: should I be running my query statement in the ViewDidLoad or some please else to get the variable in the textfield.  Basically, all I want to do is pull a record based on the value in the textfield upon returning from another UIViewController.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, your `viewDidLoad` won't be called if your original view was never dealloced. The delegate methods that will be called are `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear:`.
You can pass the value from the second viewController back to the first one with a custom made delegate method. What you should keep in mind is that you should do the query with the `NSString` you pass back with the delegate method, and place it in the textField during `viewWillAppear:`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you both! I will try that later and let you know. This might just fix my problem.

Comment: Thank you both again for pointing me in the right direction. That worked great! I ended up using the viewDidAppear because the textfield was not updated in time using the viewWillAppear.

Comment: Glad to help. If you find your question to be answered, please close the question by selecting one of the replies as best answer. Good luck with the project!

Answer (score 1):

`viewDidLoad` is only called when the view controller is loaded up from a nib. If you are switching back to one view controller from another, it won't be executed again. Try putting the code in `viewWillAppear`.